# WPF hide Tooltip for button in Style

Tags: wpf

I have a `Button` which is defined through template:

```
<Button Name="DialogOk" Grid.Column="0" Margin="4,0,0,0" Content="{Binding OkButtonText}" 
                    ToolTip="{Binding OkButtonShortcut}" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonOk}"
                    Click="DialogOk_Click" Visibility="{Binding DialogOkButtonVisibility}" />
```

The Style is defined in `ResourceDictionary`:

```
    <Style x:Key="ButtonOk" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid>
<Rectangle x:Name="ButtonBackground" Color="Red"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="ButtonText" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                            <TextBlock  x:Name="ButtonCustomToolTip" 
                                Text="{TemplateBinding ToolTip}" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                FontSize="10" Foreground="Yellow" 
                                Visibility="{TemplateBinding ToolTip, Converter={StaticResource StringToVisibility}}">
                                <TextBlock.BitmapEffect>
                                    <DropShadowBitmapEffect
                                        ShadowDepth="1"
                                        Softness="0"
                                        Color="Black"
                                        Opacity="0.4"
                                        Direction="270"
                                        />
                                </TextBlock.BitmapEffect>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Grid>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <!-- triggers there -->
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

`ButtonCustomToolTip` is collapsed, when `OkButtonShortcut` string is empty.

But I still see the default tooltip like an empty white rectangle 
[image]
when the cursor is over my button. How can I remove this default tooltip area?

Comment: You're collapsing the `TextBlock` **NOT** an actual `ToolTip`.

Comment: I know. That's why I'm asking how to collapse ToolTip

Comment: `ToolTip="{x:Null}"`

Comment: Good point, but then I need to set my custom tolltip somehow else, which I don't want to do. So let it be back-up way. Any other ways? Is it possible to set ToolTip style somewhere, so it was collapsed?

Comment: If you set up a trigger to set it to null only when url is empty then you will still have the `ToolTip` it will only be empty when trigger sets it.

Comment: You can add a style for tooltip to the resources section of your button style, and use a trigger to hide it for string.Empty, null, or any other value you want hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be achieved with a style in the resources section of your parent style.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ExampleButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ToolTip">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <!-- Add triggers for values you want to hide. -->
                        <Trigger Property="Content" Value=" ">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <!-- Tooltip not hidden -->
        <Button Margin="10" Height="50" Width="100" Content="{Binding OkButtonText}" 
                Style="{DynamicResource ExampleButtonStyle}"
                Visibility="{Binding DialogOkButtonVisibility}"
                ToolTip="Hello">
        </Button>
        <!-- Tooltip hidden -->
        <Button Margin="10" Height="50" Width="100" Content="{Binding OkButtonText}" 
                Style="{DynamicResource ExampleButtonStyle}"
                Visibility="{Binding DialogOkButtonVisibility}"
                ToolTip=" ">
        </Button>
        <!-- Tooltip not hidden because trigger doesn't hide it. -->
        <Button Margin="10" Height="50" Width="100" Content="{Binding OkButtonText}" 
                Style="{DynamicResource ExampleButtonStyle}"
                Visibility="{Binding DialogOkButtonVisibility}"
                ToolTip="">
        </Button>
        <!-- Tooltip hidden -->
        <Button Margin="10" Height="50" Width="100" Content="{Binding OkButtonText}" 
                Style="{DynamicResource ExampleButtonStyle}"
                Visibility="{Binding DialogOkButtonVisibility}"
                ToolTip="{x:Null}">
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

And found a solution how to redefine ToolTip style:

```
<Button Name="BtnOk" Grid.Column="0" Margin="4,0,0,0" Content="{Binding OkButtonText}" 
                    ToolTip="{Binding OkButtonShortcut}" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonOk}"
                    Click="DialogOk_Click">
                <Button.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="ToolTip" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToolTip}}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
                                    <Grid Visibility="Collapsed"></Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Resources>
            </Button>
```